# Can we say that: $ \sum_{n\geq 1}{\frac{1}{n}(f_n(\omega)-g_n(\omega))}<\infty\qquad a.e $

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite mesure space, and $\{f_n\}$  and $\{g_n\}$ two $L^1$-bounded  sequences, such that :
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}{\frac{1}{n}(F_n(f_n)(\omega)-g_n(\omega))}<\infty\qquad a.e
$$
with: $F_n(f_n)=f_n1_{|f_n|\leq n}$

Can we say that:
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}{\frac{1}{n}(f_n(\omega)-g_n(\omega))}<\infty\qquad a.e
$$

Comment: We have $\sup_n\|f_n\|_1<\infty$. Then, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$, such that: for all $n\geq 1$ we have
$$|f_n|\leq n_0~~ a.e.~$$Then, for all $n\geq n_0$:
$$F_n(f_n)=f_n$
hence, we have the desired result.

Comment: The argument you suggest seems to assume a bound on $\|f_n\|_1$ rather than  $\|f_n\|_\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f_n$ be independent random variables where $f_n$ takes  values $0, 2n$ with $\mu(f_n=2n)=1/n$ for each $n$. Take $g_n=0$ for all $n$. Then $F_n(f_n)=0$ for all $n$ so the hypothesis holds, but the conclusion fails: $\sum_n (f_n/n) = 2\sum_n 1_{\{f_n=2n\}}$ is infinite a.e. by the Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: But in book Two-Scale Stochastic Systems Asymptotic Analysis and Control by Kabanov, Yu.M., Pergamenshchikov, S, on page 254, the author says that: the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\zeta_{k}^{(k)}-\eta_k}$$
converges a.s  with $\zeta^{(c)}=\zeta 1_{\{|\zeta|\leq c\}}$. Since only a finite number of $\zeta_{k}^{(k)}(\omega)$ is different from $\zeta_{k}(\omega)$, the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\zeta_{k}-\eta_k}$$
also converges a.s.

Comment: Maybe you can attach a scan of the relevant pages. There could  be additional  assumptions there that would imply the desired conclusion.